# Magento payment process giving problem

Tags: magento

In my magento store...
The customer is redirected to EBS when he tried to pay.
And then he didnt do the payment process, and EBS did not charge anything.
Admin panel, order details show he is not paid, he was only redirected to EBS.

But the email goes to the customer with successful payment. Do you have any idea what may be the possible reasons?

Thanks
********Edited**************
This problem was arising due to administrator mistake itself. Its solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the history on the order, it's possible that there was a payment notification and a reversal. It may also show you when the customer was notified for their order.

Comment: This problem was arising due to administrator mistake itself. Its solved now.